# Exactly one fixed point and two periodic solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was asked to give a differential equation such that the equation has exactly two periodic solutions and one constant solution.

The teacher wrote that we can write the equation in polar coordinates.

Can someone give me a direction because I don't have a clue ...

Comment: Write down such a solution and differentiate it till you have something you can express in terms of the original solution you wrote down.

Comment: @Paul What do you mean? I tried thinking about drawing of such solutions , but I didn't succeed..

Comment: Here's one approach: try to create a fixed point at the origin, and have the two periodic solutions be two concentric circles centered at the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about $\frac{dr}{dt} = r(r-1)(r-2), \frac{d \, \theta}{dt} = 1?$ has two periodic solutions $r = 1, r = 2$ and a constant solution $r = 0.$

Comment: Can you give me a hint of how you found this equation?

Comment: nice periodic solution like that of $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + x = 0$ has periodic solutions with the trajectory given by $r = constant.$ i used that to make the right hand side of the equation. the equation for $\theta$ any positive function would do. i chose constant angular velocity.